# python bs4, how to scrape this text in html?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the site url:https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/421/0006111920

I want to scrape "5" on the below html.

I used this code: soup.select_one('span.u_likeit_text._count').get_text()

the result is '추천'

html code

```
<span class="u_likeit_text _count num">5</span>
```

Comment: add timer to wait for it

Comment: A [mcve] should be included in the [question itself](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/90527). Please read the help center documentation on asking, especially on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Main issue here that the count is dynamically generated by `JavaScript` and not present in `response` and so your `soup`.

You could use `selenium` to render the page like a browser will do and convert the `driver.page_source` to your `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://n.news.naver.com/mnews/article/421/0006111920")
time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

soup.select_one('span.u_likeit_text._count').get_text()
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate the classes using space, instead of connecting over dot.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("<span class='u_likeit_text _count num'>5</span>", 'html.parser')
print(soup)
seven_day = soup.find_all("span" , class_="u_likeit_text _count num")
print(seven_day[0].text)
```

Comment: we have to use 'soup' like 'soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')' in the real,,,actually.